# Problems with relational quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Are there any theoretical issues with Rovelli's interpretation? 
And just from extrapolation of the macroscopic world making much more sence through Einstein's relative description, is it reasonable to suspect that the quantum world also lacks absolutes?

Comment: Are you referring to the book "Quantum Gravity"?